# 301 Per Redirect .htaccess w/ match to a set of words

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I am trying to edit .htaccess to do 301 redirect from old domain to new. I was wondering if there's a way to do a 301 redirect that matches a certain keywords. So instead of writing 301 for each line, is there a way to redirect if apple or oranges or bananas show up after /blog/ with a couple lines of code and have them all 301 perm redirect to /blog/fruits/?

Example:

```
/blog/apple/
/blog/oranges/
/blog/bananas/
```

301 redirect to

```
/blog/fruits/
```

Comment: Is the new domain on the same webspace as the old domain? Do you have existing redirects in .htaccess - are you using mod_alias (`Redirect`) or mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with mod_rewrite, for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(apple|oranges|bananas)/ /blog/fruit/ [R=301,L]
```

This literally redirects just the 3 URLs listed in the question. If you wanted to redirect from `/blog/apple/<something>` to `/blog/fruit/<something>` then you can modify the above `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(apple|oranges|bananas)/(.*) /blog/fruit/$2 [R=301,L]
```

> Example: /blog/the-oranges-is-good-fruit/ would match or /blog/my-apples-and-oranges/ would match and triggers the 301 redirect

To match URLs where these *words* are contained anywhere inside that *path segment* then the above `RewriteRule` can be changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/[^/]*(apple|oranges|bananas)[^/]*/ /blog/fruit/ [R=301,L]
```

The `[^/]*` matches any number of characters that are *not* slashes (path segment delimiter).

Comment: Thank you @w3dk, will it covers if there's wild cards characters in front or end of these sets of characters? could i just add the * wild card like this? ^blog/*(apple|oranges|bananas)*/ ?

Comment: What are you trying to match specifically? You can't simply add "wild cards characters in front or end" - this is a _regular expression_ (regex), not a _glob pattern_. (In a regex, the `*` matches the previous element 0 or more times.)

Comment: Basically, i want to 301 redirect /blog/<set of words>/ so if it contains substrings of apple, oranges, or bananas and it'll redirect to url of my choice. Example: /blog/the-oranges-is-good-fruit/ would match or /blog/my-apples-and-oranges/ would match and triggers the 301 redirect. Does this make sense?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there were a way to do this, you might find that you're actually doing the same thing in 2 different ways.

Is there a difference between writing several individual 301 redirects and writing some script (I'm not even sure whether you'd be able to accomplish this with .htaccess) that uses some list/array of keywords that you needed to input by hand?

If the *idea* of writing that many redirects is daunting. I would suggest using a spreadsheet and the CONCATENATE formula to make your life very easy:

[image: formula]

[image: result]

=CONCATENATE($A$23,A26," ",B26)

Comment: I am trying to reduce the amount of written lines in .htaccess especially if i have more than 1000 url redirects that need to be done